# Finding where a row changes for one column based on a list of matching words

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I work in healthcare and one of the tasks I've been given is to find out whether a column changes under certain criteria. I should only output the claims that do so.

In more detail, the data is organized by Claim ID. Each claim can have multiple entries for pcpProvType and claimServiceType. I should only keep the rows where pcpProvType changes, by row, from NULL, '', or "NO PROVIDER TYPE".

See below... In this instance, on row three, the pcpProvType changes to "AGENCIES". Given that change, I need to return the entire claim as denoted by claimid. I suppose I could just save the claimid and pull that after, which seems easier for that part of it?

If I have a claim that starts with a pcpProvType that is not NULL, '', or "NO PROVIDER TYPE", I can just ignore that claim and move on to the next one.

I've tried using LEAD() doing something like:

```
SELECT claimid, LEAD(pcpProvType, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY claimid) AS Lead_Value FROM #Claims
```

But not sure of the code/logic in SQL to tie that together to do what I want.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Can `pcpProvType` change back to empty string, null or "NO PROVIDER TYPE"? If so, does it matter what the last value is? I mean, if it started as "AGENCIES" but then changed back to "NO PROVIDER TYPE", would you still need to return that claim? What if it started as "NO PROVIDER TYPE", then changed to "AGENCIES", then back to "NO PROVIDER TYPE"? What I'm essentially trying to get at, can the problem be narrowed down to just "claim has both empty/null/NO PROVIDER TYPE `pcpProvType` and a different value, in any order"?

Comment: @AndriyM So, it can change back and be of no consequence. The only thing of interest is if it starts with the NULL, "NO PROVIDER TYPE", etc. and then changes to one of the items in my list. Looking at the example I posted, pcpProvType on row 1 is "NO PROVIDER TYPE". That would be the base "case" I suppose. That should not trigger anything. Same with row 2. In row 3 pcpProvType changes to "AGENCIES". In that case I want the query to output, at the very least, the claimid. At that point, I would not need any further data from that claim and would need to "skip" to the next one.

Comment: Just to be sure, what if it starts as e.g. AGENCIES then changes to NO PROVIDER TYPE, then to AGENCIES again – would that make it qualify for the output?

Comment: @AndriyM Yes. It only needs to be the first instance of encountering AGENCIES. Anything beyond that, however many rows it might encompass, and no matter the value, is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with finding actual rows that contain the changes:

```
SELECT
  *
, changed = IIF(
    pcpProvType NOT IN ('', 'NO PROVIDER TYPE') AND
    COALESCE(LAG(pcpProvType, 1, pcpProvType) OVER (PARTITION BY claimid ORDER BY startdate ASC), '') IN ('', 'NO PROVIDER TYPE')
  , 1
  , 0
  )
FROM
  #Claims
```

to get an output like this:

| stateID | claimid | provid | pcpProvType | claimServiceType | startdate | changed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| TX | 22255430359 |  | NO PROVIDER TYPE | Inpatient | 2022-01-01 | 0 |
| TX | 22255430359 |  | NO PROVIDER TYPE | Inpatient | 2022-01-01 | 0 |
| TX | 22255430359 |  | AGENCIES | Inpatient | 2022-03-20 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Then I would use that as a derived table or a CTE and applied window `MAX` to `changed` to mark an entire claim with either 1 or 0 depending if it has at least one row with a 1:

```
WITH
  changes AS
  (
    SELECT
      *
    , changed = IIF(
        pcpProvType NOT IN ('', 'NO PROVIDER TYPE') AND
        COALESCE(LAG(pcpProvType, 1, pcpProvType) OVER (PARTITION BY claimid ORDER BY startdate ASC), '') IN ('', 'NO PROVIDER TYPE')
      , 1
      , 0
      )
    FROM
      #Claims
  )
SELECT
  *
, claimHasChange = MAX(changed) OVER (PARTITION BY claimid)
FROM
  changes
;
```

for the following output:

| stateID | claimid | provid | pcpProvType | claimServiceType | startdate | changed | claimHasChange |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| TX | 22255430359 |  | NO PROVIDER TYPE | Inpatient | 2022-01-01 | 0 | 1 |
| TX | 22255430359 |  | NO PROVIDER TYPE | Inpatient | 2022-01-01 | 0 | 1 |
| TX | 22255430359 |  | AGENCIES | Inpatient | 2022-03-20 | 1 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Now it only remains to filter the results on `claimHasChange = 1`.

Here is the final query:

```
WITH
  changes AS
  (
    SELECT
      *
    , changed = IIF(
        pcpProvType NOT IN ('', 'NO PROVIDER TYPE') AND
        COALESCE(LAG(pcpProvType, 1, pcpProvType) OVER (PARTITION BY claimid ORDER BY startdate ASC), '') IN ('', 'NO PROVIDER TYPE')
      , 1
      , 0
      )
    FROM
      #Claims
  )
, changesGrouped AS
  (
    SELECT
      *
    , claimHasChange = MAX(changed) OVER (PARTITION BY claimid)
    FROM
      changes
  )
SELECT
  stateID
, claimid
, provid
, pcpProvType
, claimServiceType
, startdate
FROM
  changesGrouped
WHERE
  claimHasChange = 1
;
```